# WCF error 'Unable to connect to the remote server'

Tags: wcf, iis-7

We have a website hosted in IIS have a wcf service with below settings

- WCF(folder) is set as an application at IIS
- WCF's svc file can be browsed

Our service is connecting used to connect and retrive a file. We pass argument in return we get a file.

Issue

- this service works with proxy in an web isolated environment
- fails in Web enabled environment

Error displayed

`The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Unable to connect to the remote server'. See server logs for more details.`

Comment: It would be easy to identify if you post the code.

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan you mean WCF service code. Which I have no access we were provided wcf service(svc) file and web.config.

We got a new file and replaced it and its working now.